# Show that a metric space $M$ is compact if and only if all infinite open cover of $M$ have a proper subcover.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

Let $(M,d)$ be a metric space. Show that $M$ is compact if and only if all infinite open cover of $M$ have a proper subcover.

> **We remember:** If $\mathcal{U}$ is a cover of $M$, then a proper subcover is a proper subset $\widehat{\mathcal{U}}$ of $\mathcal{U}$ such that it is cover of $M$.

**Remark:** The diection $(\Rightarrow)$ is trivial. The problem is the direction $(\Leftarrow)$, I think hypotheses are missing, but I have not been able to find a counterexample or prove it.

This exercise I found in a book that for me is not very reliable since I have found other exercises with errors.

Comment: (More precisely, the implication (5) $\implies$ (4) that is proved there.)

Comment: What you are asking is the definition of compact.  What do think compact means?  That every sequence has a converging subsequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the answer provided in [this post](https://files.yande.re/sample/dbd256a5bdcf0debd7cf6c1517ebcdfd/yande.re%20415141%20sample%20tagme.jpg), if one can take the true statement that every metric space that is limit point compact (in other words, every infinite subset of $M$ admits a limit point in $M$) is compact as given, then one can proceed as follow:

Let $E$ be an infinite subset of $M$, suppose no point $x$ of $M$ is a limit point of $E$ then $E$ is closed and every point $x$ of $E$ has a neighborhood $V_x$ that contains no other point of $E$. $\mathcal{U} = \{V_x:x\in E\} \cup \{E^c\}$ is then an infinite open cover of $M$ and the only possible proper subcover of $\mathcal{U}$ is $\{V_x:x\in E\}$, which has no proper subcover.

Comment: Actually, $\mathcal{U}$ does not have proper subcovers.

Comment: @DiegoFonseca I can redefine one of the $V_x$ to contain $E^c$.

Comment: This is probably the intended idea, to use the limit point compactness equivalence for metric spaces. The linked (in the comments) idea by Brian is also nice: take any open cover, it has a point finite refinement (and as all point finite covers have an irreducible subcover which is finite) we can find a finite subcover of the original cover. This only uses that metric spaces are metacompact.